# When are article + possessive pronoun constructions like "Der meine ist gut" used?

Tags: article, possessive-pronoun

While hunting for information about how to construct the German possessive pronouns equivalent to "mine", "yours" etc., I found [a page on the excellent Canoo website](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss1.html) that seemed to contain the answer: You just take the pronoun stem (e.g. "mein") and append the last letter of the corresponding definite article (with a preceding "e" if the last letter is not already "e"), resulting in e.g. "meiner" for a masculine thing in the nominative case that belongs to me.  Simple enough!  **[EDIT: Fixed case]**

However...  I then saw below that

> Substitute for a noun, with article:
>
> Possessive pronouns can be used as substitutes for nouns. When these substitutes are accompanied by a definite article, they are inflected like adjectives (cf. Adjectives, Weak inflection):
>
> **Der meine** ist schneller als **der deine**
>
> **Der ihre** ist schneller als **der eure**.
>
> Wir leihen euch **die unseren**.

This has no English equivalent that I can think of, so I'm left wondering: When should this be used instead of the article-free equivalent?

Comment: Your best bet would probably to stay clear from this form with article. It sounds often quite old-fashioned. In older literature (think from Goethe to Hesse) it's quite common, but not really in modern everyday German.

Comment: @Stephie: That is a relief!  As I'm still a beginner, it's great to be able to put that in the "Don't need to know about this at all" pile :)

Comment: Put that in the "I recognize this form when I stumble over it" pile and you are set!

Comment: As for an English equivalent, just drop the article: *Mine* is faster than *yours*; *theirs* is faster than *yours*; we lend you *ours*.

Comment: I would say (from my own experience) that the form you suggest is the least common of the three, with the _Formen auf --ig_ being more common and the _Stellvertretend, ohne Artikel_ being the most common. The latter is one you might want to know how to use, and is equivalent to the English forms @AnsgarEsztermann mentioned.

Comment: @Raketenolli: Thanks, but I don't know what the "Formen auf --ig" is.  And is the "Stellvertretend, ohne Arikel" the form being used in "Meine ist schneller"?

Comment: @j_random_hacker The _Formen auf --ig_ are at the end of the _Stellvertretend, mit Artikel_ section of the canoo site you linked to. Yes, "Meine ist schneller" would be _... ohne Artikel_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auf die Frage "Wessen Schirm/Hut ist das?" antwortet man normalerweise "Das ist meiner".
Es gibt regionale Varianten wie:

> Das ist der meine.
>   Das ist der meinige.

Standard ist "meiner/meine/meines".

Added: "meiner/e/es" without noun has the same forms as "dieser/e/es"

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/dieser:Pron:Demonstr)

Comment: Warum wechselst du von German to English?